# shorter equals-method the same as longer equals-method?

Tags: java, equals

Are the two equals-methods behave the same?:

("version 1" was generated by eclipse ide, "version 2" is made by myself.)

**version 1:**

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof CoreSale))
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        return Objects.equals(id, other.id);
    }
```

**version 2 (shorter):**

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // always return false, if not instance of User
        if (obj instanceof CoreSale){
        User other = (User) obj;
        return Objects.equals(id, other.id);
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Does `obj instanceof CoreSale` implicitly checks for `this == obj` or do I have to declare this also in version 2?

Comment: your first equals has a redundant null-check, since instanceof will already check for null.

Comment: the end result may be the same, but the first is a bit more effective, because of the referential comparison it starts with. The advantage however is so limited it doesn't really matter all that much

Comment: "because of the referential comparison it starts with"? what does this mean?

Comment: if you would run if ( this.equals(this) ) -> do you really need to check for matching types,or to check if the members of both instances (which is actually only one instance sent twice) in order to know they're equal? that 's the advantage of adding if ( this == obj ) return true;
as first line. if that returns true, the objects aren't just equal, they are the same object

Comment: now, for this example it doesn't change all that much, but if your class has a lot of members, that also have complex equals methods, it might improve efficiency

Comment: @nimo23 when you say, `this==obj` it is making a referential comparison. Also the null check is a referential comparison. They'll be a bit more efficient than the instanceof check.

Comment: Why are you casting to `User` after checking whether `obj` is an instance of `CoreSale`?

Comment: Version 2 is what I always write.  Shorter and easy to read wins out over premature optimization.  If I saw a noticeable performance benefit from version 1, I might have a different opinion, but in my experience, virtually no applications are going to see a benefit.

Comment: @VGR yes, I also always use version 2, however, instead of `if (obj instanceof CoreSale)`, one can also use `if (getClass() == obj.getClass())`. Should be appropriate for most cases.. 'getClass()` is also faster than `instanceOf`..

Comment: @nimo23 I try to avoid that, is it prevents proper polymorphism.  The contract of `equals` should apply to instances of subclasses.  [AbstractList.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is a good example of this.

Comment: Regarding `instanceOf` vs `getClass()`, there's no right or wrong decision. You have to decide depending on individual circumstance. Josh Bloch has a few pages of advice on this matter in his book "Effective Java".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two pieces of code should give the same answer, except for an obscure edge-case<sup>1</sup>.

The substantive differences between them are:

1. the `this == obj` test.
2. the explicit `obj == null` test.
3. the final `if` test

Dealing with them in reverse order.

I would not expect it to matter whether you wrote this as a `obj instanceof Type` or `!(obj instanceof type)`.  Indeed, I would expect the JIT compiler to optimize based on the "direction" that the branch usually takes, and to produce equivalent code for both cases.

The `instanceof` operator implicitly tests for `null`, so the explicit `obj == null` test is unnecessary.  However, I would expect the JIT compiler to recognize this and not generate native code to check for null twice.

The `this == obj` test is implementing an explicit "short circuit" for a case that is presumed to be a frequently occurring one.

- The edge-case means that the JIT compiler would not be able to insert equivalent short circuit logic if it wasn't already in the source code / byte codes.
- It is unclear whether the short-circuit is going to improve performance or not.  It depends on the *actual* frequency with which one of these objects is compared with itself ... versus the cost of doing that.

In short, only the `this == other` test is likely to make any difference (after JIT compiling), and it may or may not be beneficial to performance.

HOWEVER .... if the performance really matters, benchmark it .... using realistic data for the benchmarking.

---

<sup>1 - The edge-case occurs because `Objects.equals(id, other.id)` might throw an exception or give an incorrect answer when `this.id` and `other.id` are the same object.  This in turn depends on the actual implementation of `Object::equals(Object)` for the actual runtime type of `id`.</sup>